# Apache 2.2 -> 2.4 Upgrade: Permission denied on /

Tags: apache-2.4

I upgraded a server from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4

Now I can not access

```
www.example.org/
```

anymore

```
www.example.org/index.php
```

is working.

I have set

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

There was some problem with my rewrite config:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
```

I replaced this by

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [L]
```

and it works.